# How to download windows xp sp2 on virtual box

Tags: virtualization, windows-xp

I recently needed to download windows xp sp 2, so that I could look at its exploits, such as MS08-67. I was downloaded the .iso, from the microsoft site: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=18242 and then tried to follow instructions on the internet on how to download it, like this one here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GYeqWEHzZI and here: https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/networking_and_servers/9781782163589/1/ch01lvl1sec09/installing-windowsxp-on-oracle-vm-virtualbox
However, the first is not about xp sp2 and I couldn't think of a way of using what it was saying, to download xp sp2 and the second one wouldn't work. [image]

I have set the settings as shown in the picture above, but when I start the machine it says FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted.

Can you please explain to me how to download windows xp sp2 on virtual box?

Comment: The ISO you downloaded is only Service Pack 2 for Windows XP. It is meant as a patch for a computer already running Windows XP. It's not bootable and cannot be used to install a fresh copy of Windows XP. You will need to find a Windows XP install ISO elsewhere, one that either already has SP2 or earlier (so you can install SP2 after installation). We unfortunately cannot help you with finding such an ISO.

Comment: I have just managed to download it through this link https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/download-windows-xp-for-free-and-legally-straight-from-microsoft-si/

Comment: How can I download xp sp2 on it?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to download POSReady 2009 ISO from Microsoft website legally, which is almost same as Windows XP SP3. But you will need product key or trial product key which was previously posted by Microsoft but then removed, but others have reposted it on various websites.